# controlling ime_action_done behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have two android activities with ime_action_done.

Activity A has it on EditText view.

There - the soft keyboard "done" closes the keyboard.

```
private void initLayout(){
    mInputText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
}
```

no `onEditorAction` overriding

Activity B has it on a custom view that extends `TokenCompleteTextView`

`(com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView extends android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView implements android.widget.TextView$OnEditorActionListener )`

There the done action does nothing.

```
  completionView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (completionView.enoughToFilter() && (adapter != null)) {
 //some logic. doesn't separate action_done from the other actions.
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
```

How can i make the second one close the soft keyboard as well?

Answer (score 1):

`mInputText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

sets the action to be the default for action_done (close keyboard)

in Activity B i used `setOnEditorActionListener` which catches the ime_action and consumes it.

so i have had to add this in Activity B:

```
completionView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      InputMethodManager imm =
          (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(completionView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

or like this:

```
 completionView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);


    completionView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


//logic
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
```